# How to do a perl variable length positive lookbehind or something comparable

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I'm sure there's a better way to do this (and I'll take an answer with a completely different approach), but I need a way to programmatically modify certain text preceded by some other qualifying strings somewhere before it.  For example a file may look like this.

```
foo bar bat car
foo shmat lat dog
blat cat mat fat
foo bat cat
```

I want to replace `bat` with `cap` whenever foo is somewhere before it on the same line.

So I thought of this.

`perl -0777 -pe 's/(?<=foo.*)bat/cap/g' file`

However, I get the error

`Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?<=foo.*)bat/ at -e line 1.`

So I'm wondering how can I do a variable length lookbehind or is there a better approach where I can get this in a one-liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\K` token (match resetter) for variable-length look-behinds in Perl:

```
foo.*\Kbat
```

[RegEx live demo](https://regex101.com/r/OgMD7s/1)

Perl:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/foo.*\Kbat/cap/g' file
```

Comment: can I have it do the replace only if there isn't some string between foo and bat?

Comment: Would you mind giving an example?

Comment: say I have `foo bar bat` and I only want to replace `bat` with `cap` if there is no `bar` in between them.

Comment: so in that example, it would do nothing, but for `for boo bat` it would.

Comment: You mean like this https://regex101.com/r/yiW7mW/1 ?

Comment: you sir are a regex genius